# Retornar Dowload Excel via Controller MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, microsoft-excel

Tenho um método que gera um arquivo excel e grava ele em um diretório, porém depois pego o caminho do diretório e preciso fazer o download do arquivo excel, mas não ocorre nada, nem erro.
Alguem pode ajudar em o que eu estou falhando?

```
[HttpGet]
    public FileResult ObterDadosClientesBDO(ParametrosListaCliente filtro)
    {
        var jsonResult = Json(InstanceResolverFor<IServicoListaClientesBDO>.Instance.ObterDadosClientesBDO(filtro).ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;

        string nomeRelatorio = string.Format("{0}{1}.xlsx","NOMERELATORIO", DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyhhmmss"));
        string caminhoRelatorio = GerarRelatorioExcel(jsonResult, nomeRelatorio);


        return File(caminhoRelatorio, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", nomeRelatorio);
    }
```

Comment: Já tentou trocar para o segundo parâmetro de File para "application/vnd.ms-excel"?

Comment: ja fiz isso, porem da na mesma coisa, não ocorre nada, nenhum erro no console tambem.

Comment: Jogue o retorno do File em um FileContentResult, verifique oque ele retorna. Se quiser coloque dentro de um try/catch que provavelmente vai te retornar o erro. Após isso edite o resultado na sua pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No seu `return` [File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.controller.file(v=vs.118).aspx) não está ocorrendo erro provavelmente por que o retorno do objeto está sendo `null`, não deixa de ser um problema, mas ocorre um **Exception Handling** neste caso e não é jogada uma exceção pois **a aplicação consegue lidar com o erro** sem prejudicar o restante do funcionamento da aplicação.

O `caminhoRelatorio` deve estar apontando o caminho errado do arquivo, para contornar isso você pode fazer um tratamento como no exemplo abaixo:

```
[HttpGet]
public FileResult ObterDadosClientesBDO(ParametrosListaCliente filtro)
{
    var jsonResult = Json(InstanceResolverFor<IServicoListaClientesBDO>.Instance.ObterDadosClientesBDO(filtro).ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;

    string nomeRelatorio = string.Format("{0}{1}.xlsx","NOMERELATORIO", DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyhhmmss"));
    string caminhoRelatorio = GerarRelatorioExcel(jsonResult, nomeRelatorio);

    var arquivo = File(caminhoRelatorio, "application/vnd.ms-excel", nomeRelatorio);

    if(arquivo == null)
    {
        //se for nulo apresenta uma mensagem de aviso antes do return
        return arquivo;
    }
    else
    {
        //Se não apenas retorne o arquivo
        return arquivo;
    }
}
```

**Referências:**

- [ActionResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.actionresult(v=vs.118).aspx)
- [Controller.File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.controller.file(v=vs.118).aspx)